# Building query in PL/pgsql with different columns based on flag

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to run the following statement in PL/pgSQL.

```
    if file_record.has_recieved_time_column then
        EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY mytemp (columnA, columnB, columnC)
                        FROM %L
                        DELIMITER '',''
                        CSV HEADER;', file_record.file_path);
    elseif file_record.has_header then
        -- dont load columnC
        EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY mytemp (columnA, columnB)
                        FROM %L
                        DELIMITER '',''
                        CSV HEADER;', file_record.file_path);
    else
        -- dont load columnC and the file has no header
        EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY mytemp (columnA, columnB)
                        FROM %L
                        DELIMITER '',''
                        CSV;', file_record.file_path);
    end if;
```

How can I avoid repeating repeating myself in this code?

Comment: You have three different `COPY` statements. What do you mean by repeating? Does the function goes on with multiple IF / ELSE ?

Comment: Ideally I would like to build up the query by somehow defining `cols = (colA, colB)` then do `if file_record.has_recieved_time_column: cols += colC` and then pass `cols` as a parameter to the `COPY` statement and do something similar for the `HEADER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating  variable `cols` with default values `columnA,columnB` and then contatenate it with `columnC` in case you need it, e.g.

```
  cols := 'columnA, columnB';
  
  IF file_record.has_recieved_time_column THEN
    cols = cols || ',columnC';
  ELSEIF file_record.has_header THEN
    cols = cols || ',columnX';
  ELSE
    .... 
  END IF;
  
  EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY mytemp (%L) FROM %L DELIMITER '',''CSV HEADER;', cols, file_record.file_path);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, is there a way to also solve the header problem in the same way, can I set a header variable which is an empty string and replace it with HEADER then use %L in the same way as you did now?

Comment: @sev absolutely. Just replace the `HEADER` in the `COPY` string with `%L` and add an extra variable in the end of the `FORMAT` command.

Comment: @sev something like `EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY mytemp (%L) FROM %L DELIMITER '',''CSV %L;', cols, file_record.file_path,header_variable);`